# Connect mobile phone to internet using desktop pc internet

Tags: internet, htc-hero

is it possible to share my desktop pc internet to my mobile phone?

im using HTC Hero and a wired internet connection on my desktop pc

Comment: mmm... Is there an option to use a proxy on Android?

Answer (score 1):

the hero's wired tethering is one-way only i.e. letting the PC share the phone's connection.  Certainly that's all you can do without jailbreaking

if you attached a wi-fi adapter to your PC, you *might* be able to set up an ad-hoc wireless network and share that... but in that case, you're just as well off just buying a wireless access point

Comment: I read this question the other way around. Already havibng working Internet access on the PC and letting the phone share that.

Comment: @Hennes - that's the same way I read and answered

Answer (score 0):

It appears [some people have attempted to do just as you describe](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=554852)... with little success. [Here's another](http://androidforums.com/htc-hero/20858-access-internet-through-pc.html). Sorry. It looks like it's not yet possible with Android (the operating system of HTC Hero).

Answer (score 0):

If the desktop has wifi and Widows 7, you can try using something like [Conectify](http://www.connectify.me/) to share the wired connection over wifi. I've only used this to share a wifi connection (sort of like a repeater really) but should work the same.

On Vista, I believe it's possible to share a wifi connection over wired but can't find anything the other way around as required in this case.